Find the area of ​triangle ABC depending on the conditions given below
In triangle $ABC$, angle $C$ measures $120°$ and side $AC$ is greater than side $BC$. Knowing that the area of ​​the equilateral triangle with side $AB$ is $31$, the area of ​​the equilateral triangle with side $AC-BC$ is $19$, calculate the area of ​​triangle $ABC$.(Answer: $4$)
I try:
$\dfrac{AB^2\sqrt3}{4}=31 \implies AB = \sqrt{\frac{124\sqrt3}{3}}$
$\dfrac{(AC-BC)^2\sqrt3}{4} = 19 \implies AC - BC = \sqrt{\frac{76\sqrt3}{3}}$
$S\triangle ABC = \frac{1}{2}.sen 120^o .AC.BC=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}.AC.BC$
$AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2.AC.BC.cos 120^o  = AC^2+BC^2+2AC.BC$
$\frac{124\sqrt3}{3} = AC^2+BC^2+\frac{2S \triangle ABC \sqrt3}{3}$
...

You need to use $\sin(120)= \frac{ \sqrt 3} 2$ and $\cos(120)= -\frac 1 2$. I would also recommend that you use lower case symbols for sides: $a \equiv BC, b \equiv AC, c \equiv AB$, it's much easier to see what's going on with algebra when you simplify the symbols you use.

In general on MathSE, this type of posted question would really benefit by embedding a corresponding geometric visualization of the problem, directly into the posted question.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of
this article
and see also this article.

You've made a good start, but there are a couple of small mistakes. As WW1's comment indicates, $\sin(120^{\circ}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\cos(120^{\circ}) = -\frac{1}{2}$. In addition, I'll use its suggestion of single lower-case letters for the triangle side lengths, i.e.,
$$a = \lvert BC\rvert, \;\; b = \lvert AC\rvert, \;\; c = \lvert AB\rvert \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Thus, with the trigonometry formula for triangle area, your final denominator of $2$ should be $4$ instead, i.e.,
$$S\triangle ABC = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \sin 120^{\circ}\cdot ab = \frac{\sqrt3}{\color{blue}{4}}\cdot ab \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Also, using $c^2 = \frac{124}{\sqrt{3}}$ and changing your factor of $2$ to $1$ in the final law of cosines formula, we get
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cdot \cos 120^{\circ} = a^2 + b^2 + \color{blue}{1}\cdot ab = \frac{124}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
In addition, we have
$$(a - b)^2 = \frac{76}{\sqrt{3}} \;\;\to\;\; a^2 + b^2 - 2ab = \frac{76}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Next, \eqref{eq3A} minus \eqref{eq4A} gives
$$3ab = \frac{48}{\sqrt{3}} \;\;\to\;\; ab = \frac{16}{\sqrt{3}} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} results in
$$S\triangle ABC = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\cdot \frac{16}{\sqrt{3}} = 4 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Excellent, thnaks my friend
